# Problems trying to run Ionic App in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

Since i upgrade Xcode to 12.2 version, i start having problems when i try to run my ionic app in iOS Simulator.

App build successfully but couldn't start in simulator, in physical device works properly. I obtain the next error message

> No target specified for emulator. Deploying to undefined simulator.
>   Device type "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.undefined" could not be found.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced same problem after updating the Mojave.

You can launch the simulator by specifying complete path to CoreSimulator for target attribute. Try following commands

```
$ ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload --consolelogs --target="iPhone-6,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2"

$ ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload --consolelogs --target="iPhone-6,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2" --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

Let me know if it didn't work for you.

Comment: If it works then please do accept as correct answer and upvote. Thanks.

Comment: when i ran that command i receive `{path}/platforms/ios/build/emulator/{appName}.app/Info.plist file` not found.
This path really does not exists, when i check my project directory i can found `{path}/platforms/ios/{appName}.app/{appName}-Info.plist` could i forgot any config?

Comment: Have you tried clean derived data folder and build again?

Comment: Yes, removed ios platform too.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have tried second command also from the post and still facing the issue?

Comment: Yes. I used both.